# Installing Git into WINDOWS system Path, still receiving Brackets Bowler errors

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows, adobe-brackets

How can I get rid of this warning message, and start making the Brackets-Bower extension start working again?

[image: Warning message]

I currently have these settings in my variables:

[image: Settings]

This is the [Brackets extension](http://github.com/albertinad/brackets-bower) spitting out the warning message.

Comment: Try changing your path so the first entry is `C:\Program Files\Git\bin`. It should be a folder, not the full path of the executable.

Comment: It works @MatthewStrawbridge ! You're a saint.

Comment: Thanks. In that case I'll put it as an answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Change your path so the first entry is C:\Program Files\Git\bin. It should be a folder, not the full path of the executable.